# Where did MySQL on Yum go?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just ran:

```
yum search mysql
```

and the usual option for installing mysqld is not there.  I'm on a Linux2 AWS EC2 instance.  Did Amazon do something to scrub it or what?

Comment: Amazon Linux, along with most other distros replaced mysql with mariadb years ago.

Comment: You must add the official MySQL yum repo: https://serverfault.com/questions/894457/amazon-linux-2-ami-aws-how-to-install-mysql-in-amazon-linux-2

Comment: ...or just use mariadb.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I figured.